# Bootstrap 3.2.0 social Glyphicons missing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

In Bootstrap 3.2.0 social Glyphicons like:
facebook, twitter, youtube etc. are missing.

Where I can find these icons ?

in earlier version of bootstrap following classes use for these icons:
fa fa-facebook
fa fa-twitter
fa fa-google-plus
fa fa-youtube

Comment: as you already say it yourself `fa fa-facebook fa fa-twitter fa fa-google-plus fa fa-youtube`  where `fa`  refers to fontawesome

Comment: Font Awesome has never been part of Bootstrap itself, it's always been separate. Bootstrap itself has [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Social icons are no longer included with Bootstrap. The recommended solution is to use Font Awesome instead.

Font Awesome is, as the name suggests, awesome.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand